# Are link only answers OK if they link to somewhere else on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, review-audits

I recently encountered [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6516471)

As with most audits, it was an obvious audit and easy to pass, BUT although we usually discourage link only answers, I thought links to Stack overflowO were OK, and the other answer by the same answerer is also OK.

Is this really a good audit? I hope people are checking what is linked when they review.

Comment: It means its definitely a dupe - which is possibly even worse

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, link only answers are not ok. Ever.

It's especially bad if it's on SO. That means it's probably a duplicate.